# TypeScript: Is there any way to have an Array of types using the typeof operator?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typeof

Given the following code:

```
class Type
{
    static Property = 10;
}

class Type1 extends Type
{
    static Property = 20;
}

class Type2 extends Type
{
    static Property = 30;
}
```

I would like to make a function that can return an array of types that all inherit from the same base, that allows access to the "static side" of the class. For example:

```
function GetTypes(): typeof Type[]
{
    return [Type1, Type2];
}
```

So now ideally I could go:

```
GetTypes(0).Property; // Equal to 20
```

However it doesn't seem like there is syntax for storing multiple typeof types in an array.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there is. Your code is correct minus the return type of the `GetTypes` function. (To be clear Steve's answer would solve your issue as well, this is just another approach without making use of interfaces).

Change the return type of the `GetTypes` function to:

```
function GetTypes(): Array<typeof Type>
{
    return [Type1, Type2];
}
```

This should to the trick.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer I'm looking for. I didn't think to use the Array constructor to define the typing, I was trying to do it with the [] notation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to create an interface that describes the properties (or operations) supported by the type (that don't belong to an instance of the type):

```
interface Test {
    x: number;
}

class MyType {
    static x = 10;
}

class MyOtherType {
    static x = 20;
}

var arr: Test[] = [MyType, MyOtherType];

alert(arr[0].x.toString());
alert(arr[1].x.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

No. It is currently only supported for single identifiers. I have made a feature request here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1481

Nonetheless you can simply create a dummy interface to capture `typeof Type` and then use it in an Array i.e:

```
class Type
{
    static Property = 10;
}

class Type1 extends Type
{
    static Property = 20;
}

class Type2 extends Type
{
    static Property = 30;
}

// Create a dummy interface to capture type
interface IType extends Type{}

// Use the dummy interface
function GetTypes(): IType[]
{
    return [Type1, Type2];
}

GetTypes[0].Property; // Equal to 20
```

[See it on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Type%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20Property%20=%2010;%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Type1%20extends%20Type%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20Property%20=%2020;%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Type2%20extends%20Type%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20Property%20=%2030;%0A%7D%0A%0A//%20Create%20a%20dummy%20interface%20to%20capture%20type%0Ainterface%20IType%20extends%20Type%7B%7D%0A%0A//%20Use%20the%20dummy%20interface%0Afunction%20GetTypes%28%29%3a%20IType%5B%5D%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5BType1,%20Type2%5D;%0A%7D%0A%0AGetTypes%5B0%5D.Property;%20//%20Equal%20to%2020)

Comment: In the language specification it says that the type query expression is restricted to a single identifier or a sequence of identifiers separated by periods, which is why the array syntax is not allowed. See section 3.6.3 on Type Queries.